# Visual Studio Cordova project won't build when running on Parallels

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, parallels

I installed Visual Studio on Windows running in Parallels on my Mac.

When creating a new Cordova project and to debug with VS Android Emulator, it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
```

I read somewhere that this happens when sharing is enabled with Parallels. If I disable sharing I get a new error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\Mac\Home\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (The network path was not found)
```

Which I understand, because \Mac\Home will obviously no longer be available.

What I can't figure out is who or what is looking in \Mac\Home for Gradle, or anything else for that matter. Is it my VS installation? Something in my application? Android SDK? Java? Some NPM package?

Edit:
I'd done a full repair install of Visual Studio, I've reinstalled Node from scratch, Android SDK, and JDK - who knows about \Mac\Home?????

Answer (score 0):

It was Java. \\Mac\Home existed when the JDK was installed, and installing a newer version of the JDK didn't make VS use it - I manually set it in Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordove -> Environment Variable Overrides